# PARTITION by Two fields in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

This is an Answer to question "ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY in Tableau".
{PARTITION  [A],[B]: {ORDERBY [C]:ROW_NUMBER()}} generates an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax will work fine in Tableau Prep but will not work in Tableau Desktop.  One of the many gaps and shortcomings in Tableau